# Prove that $h$ is not recursive

Tags: logic, computability

Where $x$ is a code number for a 1-place recursive function, define $h:\mathbb{N^2}\longmapsto\mathbb{N}$ as follows:

- $h(x,y)=1$ if $x$ is defined for $y$
- $h(x,y)=0$ if not.

This is problem 6.9 in Boolos, Burgess, and Jeffrey's Computability and Logic 5th Edition. In Burgess's student manual he invites the reader to consider the minimization of the 2-place function $g:\mathbb{N^2}\longmapsto\mathbb{N}$ defined as follows:

- $g(x,y)=|x-y|+y$

Burgess notes that $\mathrm{Mn}[g]$ is defined for $0$. Since $\mathrm{Mn}[g](0)=0$ but that, otherwise, for all $x>0$ it is undefined.

Given all of this, I tried to reason as follows:

1. Suppose $n$ is the code number for $\mathrm{Mn}[g]$
2. Then $h(n,0)=1$, as, per above, $\mathrm{Mn}[g]$ is defined for $0$
3. But if we try to compute $h(n,1)$, we need to compute $\mathrm{Mn}[g](1)$ which we cannot since $\mathrm{Mn}[g]$ is not defined for $1$.
4. As a result, $h(n,1)\neq0$, but rather $h(n,1)$ is undefined.

But this is where I am lost. I don't see how this would show that $h$ is not recursive. Also, I am not sure if my steps 1-4 above are on the right track at all.

I have found similar problems in the OLP's Computability chapter and in Leary and Kristiansen's Friendly Intro to Mathematical Logic. But their proofs that $h$ is not recursive follow a path involving Kleene's Normal Form Theorem and seem to basically attack the problem by showing that if $h$ were recursive then it would imply that a "diagonal" recursive function previously proved not to be computable would be computable. Hence, by reductio, $h$ cannot be recursive. But none of that material is at all present in Boolos, Burgess, Jeffrey text (at least for Chapters 1,2,6,or 7).

Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: What is the meaning of $\text{Mn}[g]$? By context it seems to be a function which takes one argument, but I cannot guess what is the intended value of $\text{Mn}[g](k)$.

Comment: Also, have you learned any nonrecursive functions at all? Irregardless of what one might be invited to do in the student manual, if you have already proved that certain functions are recursive, you can attempt to reduce the function $h$ to one of those.

Comment: To compute $h(n,1)$ you don't have to compute $Mn[g](1)$, you just use the program for $h$ (which it's assumed to exist in order to get a contradiction), and then you would get $h(n,1) = 0$.

Comment: @Lee Mosher, the only non-recursive function we've learned is the diagonal function $d$ where $d(n)=f_n(n)+1$ for a given enumeration of recursive functions: $f_1,f_2,f_3,...$

Comment: @Sam So I assume $h$ is recursive and then get $h(n,1)=0$ because $n$ is not defined for $1$? But how does that generate a contradiction?

Comment: @beachtrees It doesn't generate a contradiction (at least not yet). I'm just pointing out a problem with step 3 in your argument.

Comment: @Sam Ah. Got it. Is a reductio a viable strategy here? I guess I don't understand the connection between $g$ and the proof that $h$ is not recursive. Also, with the diagonal function $d$ the proof establishes that it is computable but not primitive recursive. So I can't assume it could get a code number and so be in the domain of $h$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is basically the halting problem. Let $f = Mn[g]$ and define $T(x)=f(h(x,x))$. If $h$ is recursive, then $T$ is recursive, so it has a code number $m$. But then we have: $$T(m) \text{ is defined} \iff h(m,m) = 0 \iff T(m)  \text{ is undefined}$$

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much.